# Passing 2 parameters to "Open with.."

Tags: gnome, diff

I do a lot of diffing and I would like to have kdiff3 under "Open with...". When from console I execute kdiff3 file1 file2 then kdiff is runned and it compares those two files. however this does not work with "open with".

If I select two files and click "Open with..." and type "kdiff3" then kdiff is runned with only first file. is it possible to pass two files to kdiff as open with?

Answer (score 1):

Open with is not meant for such a use-case. Even if it were possible, by (for eg) by creating a second shell script that would launch kdiff3, it would either hardcode the second file in thE script itself, or have to ask you for it.

What you ideally need is a nautilus/dolphin extension that would call kdiff3 for you with the selected files.

[this](http://www.giuspen.com/software/nau3pyext/kdiff3-compare.py) is a nautilus extension that does exactly that(keiff3 support) while [diff-ext](http://diff-ext.sourceforge.net) offers far more features, and works even in windows.